# How to debug bazel compiling c++ codes?

Tags: c++, debugging, bazel

I'm trying to compile c++ codes using bazel, but it tells Segmentation fault: 11, when I run it. So, I want to debug where it gets failure.
Could you know how to proceed?
I've built files already by bazel, but cannot execute the program.

Comment: If your binary is built using Bazel you debug a segfault exactly the same way as if it was built with any other build system. The fact that you're using Bazel is completely irrelevant. Run it under a debugger and see where the segfault is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Bazel with `-c dbg`:

```
bazel build -c dbg //path/to/your:binary
```

This produces the binary `bazel-bin/path/to/your/binary` on Linux/macOs, or `bazel-bin\path\to\your\binary.exe` on Windows.

Then, as [@Sean Burton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2139902/sean-burton) says, run the resulting binary under a normal debugger.

Comment: I run this command `bazel build //src/app:main --run_under=gdb` and the on the .exe file I run `gdb main.exe` and I get **No symbol table loaded.  Use the "file" command.**